# Validar rfc con Expresiones

Tags: php, javascript

Alguna idea de como Validar RFC correctamente con JS actualmente tengo esta expresión:

```
^([A-ZÑ&]{3,4}) ?(?:- ?)?(\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])) ?(?:- ?)?([A-Z\d]{2})([A\d])$
```

**Tiene los siguientes errores:**

- Ingreso 12 números me los acepta.
- Ingreso 9 números y 3 caracteres lo acepta
- Ingreso únicamente 9 números lo acepta

**La idea es que únicamente acepte los puntos en el siguiente orden:**

- Ingresar 3 o 4 caracteres.
- Seguido fecha 6 números enteros.
- 3 caracteres alfanuméricos.

Espero me puedan orientar es para un trabajo escolar. Se agradece cualquier aporte Saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy muy seguro de que en los RFC esté permitida la letra Ñ, pese a ello, veo que la has agregado dentro de los caracteres aceptados.
De cualquier modo, la siguiente es una breve modificación a la expresión que incluyes, funciona para el caso en el cual se incluye la homoclave

```
^([A-ZÑ&]{3,4})(?:- )?(\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))(?:- )?([A-Z\d]{2})([A\d])$
```

y esta es una breve modificación para la versión en la cual acepta también aquellos casos en los cuales el RFC no incluye la homoclave:

```
^([A-ZÑ&]{3,4})(?:- )?(\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))(?:- )?(([A-Z\d]{2})([A\d]))?$
```

Una versión simplificada en la cual no aceptas espacios en blanco ni guiones sería la siguiente:

```
^([A-Z]{3,4})(\d{2}(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))([A-Z\d]{2}(?:[A\d]))?$
```

Espero que te sea útil alguna de las opciones.

Comment: Perfecto Erik probé  la  ultima   y funciona  perfecto muchas  gracias!!